# My android app is executed but not showing in the emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I am new to android app development. my app is executed successfully within a sec. but it not showing up in the emulator device. I am unable to select the virtual device from the dropdown options of android studio. I also updated the SDK to the latest version and ensured that the gradle Build is successful.I am not sure why the app is not been shown in the emulator device. The emulator device is running without my app and the app is also executed successfully but I a unable to see the app in the Virtual device of the emulator. I also tried by wiping the data of the virtual device but that was also not helped me.

Can some one please help me on this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's Very Simple.

01 - Save Project - Close Project
02 - Bottom Have Avd Manager
03 - Run Emulator Frist.

04 - Successfully Start Emulator Open Project And You Can Select Emulator and Run project.

(Frist Sync project gradle files and clean project-rebuild project)

Comment: Hi @Asith, Thanks for your reply. I followed your steps but still facing the same problem.

Comment: Hi @Asith, When I Save and close the project the android studio is getting closed. I reopened the project again and synched the gradle files,I did project rebuild also before running it. and Tried to run it facing the same problem Still I cannot see my project in the emulator. And also I cannot select the virtual device from the drop down as It is frozen(Shown in screenshot).

Comment: Are You Run Emulator? Frist run emulator for device manager.

Comment: Hi @Asith,

I did run the emulator but nothing worked.

Comment: I also uninstalled the android studio and again re installed it . but this also not helped me. Still facing the same issue.

Comment: @AsithMadushan - please stop telling people to contact you offsite, along with your contact links. This isn't how Stack Overflow works.